# neo4j fails to start after ebs volume size increase

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j

I have had Neo4j running fine in a 300GB EBS volume. I doubled the volume size, and now Neo4j won't start. It just seems to hang, with nothing reported in the console.log.

If I delete the graph.db directory, it will start.

I suspect the increased block size has corrupted the database.

Any ideas?

Comment: When [expanding an EBS volume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html), you have to stop the EBS instance. If you did not gracefully stop the neo4j server **before** you stopped the instance, then that would have almost certainly corrupted your DB.

Comment: Then I guess I've been extremely lucky then, because I never stop Neo4j before rebooting/re-starting the instance, and I've never had this issue.

Comment: How long did you wait?  A volume resize of course is actually creating a new volume, and depending on how much work is done with the db file on restart, it could take hours before the entire volume has been loaded from the snapshot.  Meanwhile, all the data on the volume is logically available but there is a first-touch penalty.  My testing has suggested that a reasonable round number rule of thumb is that you're potentially looking at around 1 hour per 20 GB of the original volume's size, for full performance.  With anything other than a database (any database), this tends to go unnoticed.

Comment: I did not realize that when creating a new volume from a snapshot that all the data was not immediately available. Is this caveat mentioned anywhere in the documentation?

Comment: I found where this is mentioned in AWS's documentation. Now the question is, how can I know when all the data has been migrated, and then proceed to start up and use my database?